# AWS Cognito Pre authentication lambda trigger on federation login

Tags: amazon-cognito

In my project we have some federation providers are integrated(e.g., outlook). So whenever user logs in via a valid configured federation domain name then no issues, but whenever a user tries to login via federation with an unsupported(not integrated) domain name (e.g., XXX@gmail.com), cognito just redirects to the same login page without showing any error message saying `Unsupported Domain`.
To handle error we thought of triggering the pre-authentication lambda, but pre-authentication lambda is not triggered for federation login flow. It triggers only for login via Cognito User Identity Pool.
Question is that are there any alternatives where I trigger pre-authentication lambda for federation login flow in AWS Cognito to handle error message on unsupported federation user domain name attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a project in which we have to add a user in DynamoDb whenever a new user signs up, we were providing Google, Azure, and (email, password) as options for sign-in/up. Let's get straight to the point. I solved this problem by attaching my lambda to POST_CONFIRMATION_TRIGGER of Cognito and mapping identity attributes then saving these values in my DynamoDb, it works perfectly but I had to spend 2 nights figuring this out.

if you want to know, how I achieve this then let me know.
tech stack: Aws amplify, appsync, cognito, dynamoDb, lambda

PS. POST_CONFIRMATION trigger works only the first time.

Comment: I'm currently implementing something similar. I need to synchronise cognito users with my own user metadata. POST_CONFIRMATION only triggers with email signup, not federated identities, as they do not have a confirmation part (I assume). PRE-SIGNUP cannot be used, as a user is not created yet, and therefore does not have a sub to use as unique identifier. Also, there's no triggers for updating attributes or deleting users.

How do you solve updating/deleting users, and adding both email and google users via lambdas?

Comment: UPDATE: POST_CONFIRMATION does actually trigger federated signup, but it creates a duplicate email, if the user has already signed up with email/password, and the lambda will fail, if your own database has unique emails. I guess you'll have to link the users, in case the email has been used

Answer (score 0):

You can create similar lambda function like the one that is triggered for Pre Authentication check, and then call it via API Gateway before login via federation.

Comment: But with cognito provided login page for federation user login flow I don't see any lambda available to configure the trigger in AWS cognito.

Comment: Yes, you need to call it via API Gateway, it will not be triggered automatically. If you are not familiar with API Gateway, or how lambda functions can be called from aws sdk, I suggest you check AWS developers guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Answer (score 0):

The pre-authentication trigger will trigger for federated login. However, according to [its aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html), pre-authentication trigger will not happen if the user does not exist within the user pool already.

```
Note
Triggers are dependant on the user existing in the user pool before trigger activation.
```

The user from your successful federated login does not exist in cognito yet, and it will be added to the cognito pool after the successful login.

Since cognito will add the federated user to its user pool, its a sign-up event. You should use the [pre-sign-up trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) instead. Federated login will trigger your pre-sign-up lambda as expected.